# rapidjson extract key and value

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm trying to extract the key and the value of an object in array but don't find the proper getter:

```
 for (Value::ConstValueIterator itr = document["params"].Begin(); itr != document["params"].End(); ++itr)
{
    for (Value::MemberIterator m = itr->MemberBegin(); m != itr->.MemberEnd(); ++m) {

    }       
}
```

in the second loop, I want to extract the key and value from the iterator separately. how to  do the extraction?

Comment: Could you show your JSON text?

Answer (score 12):

Suppose V is a JSON object which has key-value object. You can retrieve data like this.

```
const rapidjson::Value& V;
for (Value::ConstMemberIterator iter = V.MemberBegin(); iter != V.MemberEnd(); ++iter){
    printf("%s\t", iter->name.GetString());
    printf("%s\t", iter->value.GetString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`m` is `Member*`, where Member is

```
struct Member { 
    GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator> name;     //!< name of member (must be a string)
    GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator> value;    //!< value of member.
};
```

Thus the proper getter for the key is `m->name`.

That much is obvious from "rapidjson/document.h".